# Fourier series pointwise convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, pointwise-convergence

As far as I know, there are theorems like Jordan-Dini’s that ensure pointwise convergence of the Fourier Series of a periodic function to the function itself given that one-sided limits and derivatives exist and are finite at a point.

But what if the function is something like the periodic extension of $f(x)=\sqrt{x+\pi}$, which has vertical tangency? Or $f(x)=(x+\pi)\sin(\frac{1}{x+\pi})$, which isn`t differentiable at $x=-\pi$? Both are in $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ as they are continuous, but how can you deal with them?

Comment: You might want to check some fundamental theorems of the Fourier series theory, namely the [Dirichlet-Jordan test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%E2%80%93Jordan_test) and [Fejér's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r%27s_theorem).

Comment: The first one is bounded variation since it's monotonic so the Fourier series converges to the function or the average of the left and right limits; second one not sure exactly how you define it at $\pi$ because by periodicity it should be the value at $-\pi$ so the function is not continuous or bv

Comment: Holder continuity can address some of the issues. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series

Comment: actually even more is true - if $f$ periodic is BV on some (closed) interval $I$ that is contained in the periodicity interval, then the Fourier series of $f$ still converges same way as in the full BV case on any closed subinterval $J \subset I$ (we have pointwise convergence either to $f(x)$ or to $(f(x^+)+f(x^-))/2$ depending whether $f$ is continuous or has a jump at $x$ - BV implies those are the only two possibilities- and the convergence is uniform on any closed sub-interval where $f$ is continuous; this should take care of examples like $x \sin 1/x$ extended by periodicity